# Uninstalling django-haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have an issue with haystack https://stackoverflow.com/q/33669864/4910881 that requires me to uninstall it for now. I commented out haystack from installed apps expecting it will start throwing django import errors or similar errors but it still returning an internal server error.

```
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579793 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196]     for conn in connections.all():
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579802 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 112, in all
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579815 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196]     return [self[alias] for alias in self.connections_info]
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579823 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 100, in __getitem__
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579836 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196]     self._connections[key] = load_backend(self.connections_info[key]['ENGINE'])(using=key)
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579844 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 53, in load_backend
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579857 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196]     return import_class(full_backend_path)
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579865 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 23, in import_class
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579878 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196]     raise ImportError("The Python module '%s' has no '%s' class." % (module_path, class_name))
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.579894 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675802625792] [remote 127.0.0.1:196] ImportError: The Python module 'xapian_backend' has no 'XapianEngine' class.
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.626881 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720] mod_wsgi (pid=191252): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/kbuzz/webapps/revised/kb/kb/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.626926 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.626950 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 175, in __call__
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.626989 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]     signals.request_started.send(sender=self.__class__)
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627014 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 198, in send
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627041 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]     response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627057 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/__init__.py", line 59, in reset_search_queries
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627082 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]     for conn in connections.all():
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627097 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 112, in all
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627123 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]     return [self[alias] for alias in self.connections_info]
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627138 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 100, in __getitem__
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627161 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]     self._connections[key] = load_backend(self.connections_info[key]['ENGINE'])(using=key)
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627176 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 53, in load_backend
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627199 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]     return import_class(full_backend_path)
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627214 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 23, in import_class
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627237 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720]     raise ImportError("The Python module '%s' has no '%s' class." % (module_path, class_name))
[Thu Nov 12 15:32:03.627263 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 191252:tid 139675918014208] [remote 127.0.0.1:11720] ImportError: The Python module 'xapian_backend' has no 'XapianEngine' class.
```

Comment: Make sure you have restarted the server after changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all related `.pyc` files

Comment: that's likely to cause issues I've removed it for now while I debug